# Sony, sony-smartwatch

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I have a One Question:

I newly starting developing for Sony Smart Watch 3. I established all environment setup for developing but

I can't able to connect my sony smart watch 3 with nexus 7 tablet.

So anyone please help me?

Thank you.﻿

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the little information you're providing.

But sometimes it helps to reset the smartwatch to its factory settings.

- Find 'Reset Device' in the settings menu
- tap to confirm

Also don't forget to enable USB debugging on the watch by tapping seven times on the watch's build number inside the Settings/Info screen.